# React functional component ternary operator return html element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, icons

I am trying to get some optional changes in my functional component in react using ternary operator. But the change results in an bug.

I am trying render an icon but rather, I am rendering the icon code.

```js
export const Navitem = (props) => {
    const routes = useRouter()
    const active = routes.pathname == props.link ? ' active' : null
    const submenuIcon = props.className === 'has-submenu' ? ' <i class="ti-angle-right"></i>' : null
    const badge = props.badgde !== null ? '<span className=' + props.badge + '>' + props.badgeText + '</span>' : null
    return(
        <li className={props.className + active}>
            <Link href={props.link}>
                <a><i className={props.icon}></i><span>{props.text + submenuIcon + badge}</span>
                </a>
            </Link>
            {props.children}
        </li>
    )
}
```

I am expecting a result of: `>`

But in actuality, I am getting `<i class="ti-angle-right"></i>`

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: React conditional render:https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 0):

Use JSX instead of a quoted string `'<i class="ti-angle-right"></i>'`:

```
'has-submenu' ? <i class="ti-angle-right" /> : null
```